# Django duplicate model definition/fields

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, metaclass

Here's what I was using:

```
class a(models.Model):
    x = models.CharField()

class b(a):
    pass
```

The problem with this is that when an instance of b is created, an instance of a is also created, I'm guessing this is because b is inheriting some property that Django assigns such as the database table. I would like to have b have all the fields and methods so that this duplication does not happen. How can this be done **without simply copy and pasting all the code from a to b or using an abstract base class c and have a and b both inherit from c (I'd like to only have two models/classes)?** Would you have to use metaclasses?

Answer (score 6):

```
class A(models.Model):
    #some fields here
    x = models.CharField()
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class B(A):
    pass
```

`A` will be an abstract class, and you cannot use this class alone. But as I understood, you want to have two real classes `A` and `B`. In this case you need a third (abstract) class `C`. So they will inherit the fields from the abstract one and add extra fields to them.

For example:
suppose that abstract is C

```
class C(models.Model):
    # the common fields 
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
class A(C):
    #extra fields if you need or pass
class B(C):
     #extra fields if you need or pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `a` an [abstract model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes):

```
class a(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    x = models.CharField()
```

Also note that class names should be uppercase, so it should be `A` and `B`, but `x` is correct.

Comment: wouldn't this make it so that instances of a can't be created? While obviously the solution would be to create a third class as the abstract base class and have a and b inherit from it, is there any way to do it with just two classes/models? Sorry I didn't make this clear, I'll update the question